# PyDev on Eclipse does not stop at breakpoints

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, tryton

I've been development software for OpenERP and Tryton for four years, usally with Eclipse and PyDev. Today I've found with the unusual case where the debugger does not stop at breakpoints with the only message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

I've ensured that I started the server with the debugger option, and the skip all breakpoints button is not pressed.

I suspect I have a bug in my code, but I cannot figure out how to find it. Any idea will be wellcome.

Comment: You can debug the server without using PyDev. What you have to do is the following: add import pdb; pdb.set_trace() where you want to start debugging and run the server from a console. Once the pdb line is hit, you can debug directly from the console. If you have the same result with this procedure the problem is not related with PyDEV.

Comment: Thanks pokoli. This worked for me, although it is harder than PyDev.